# Redirecting .bat output when using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to redirect the output of a .bat script to a file. The script is run on another machine.

The commented line works. The t.txt file is produced in the expected location. I cannot convince PowerShell to produce the output file when the ScriptBlock is used.

The current result is that the $sb text is printed to the PowerShell console running this script. No file is produced on SERVER2. What do I need to get the output written to the file specified in the scriptblock?

```
$cn = 'SERVER2'
$Logfile = "D:\DBA\Scripts\monlogs\monlog_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss').txt"
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create("{ & cmd.exe /C D:\DBA\Scripts\mon_test_001.bat >`"$Logfile`" }")
### Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cn -ScriptBlock { & D:\DBA\Scripts\mon_test_001.bat >D:\DBA\Scripts\monlogs\t.txt 2>&1 }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cn -ScriptBlock $sb
```

**EDIT**

After BenH's comment, I found the following to work as expected. Note that the parameter needed to have the $ escaped.

```
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create("param(`$Logfile) & cmd.exe /C D:\DBA\Scripts\mon_test_001.bat >`"$Logfile`"")
```

Comment: `$logfile` inside the scriptblock when used in the invoke-command isn't in the same scope as the `$logfile` you defined. You would need to use a param block and argumentlist. (can't use the using scope when using the `Create()` method.  Also I don't believe you want the curly braces inside the `Create()` method

Comment: @BenH - Fantastic! If you will make this an answer, I will select it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than class create method, maybe casting would work? Then because you're running the scriptblock on a remote machine, use the "$using:" scope on the local variable.  (PSv3+ onwards)

```
$cn = 'SERVER2'
$Logfile = "c:\temp\$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss').txt"
[scriptblock]$sb = { & cmd.exe /C c:\temp\test.bat > "$using:Logfile" }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cn -ScriptBlock $sb
```

Otherwise for earlier versions, you will need to use a param block and -ArgumentList:

```
[scriptblock]$sb = {param($logpath) & cmd.exe /C c:\temp\test.bat > "$logpath" }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cn -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $Logfile
```

Comment: @BenH: There's no problem with _creating_ the script block with a `$using:` reference beforehand; what matters is the context in which it is _invoked_.

Comment: @mklement0 `$test = 'test'; $sb = [scriptblock]::create($using:test)` returns the error message _A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is
used with Invoke-Command, the Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer._

Comment: @BenH: Your example uses `$using:test` _outside_ of a script block, which is why it breaks; what I was talking about is `$test = 'test'; $sb = { $using:test }`, as used in Kenny's answer.

Comment: @mklement0 That makes sense.